# Copy numpy array contents without changing values in array with different dtype

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I get following result with numpy array when I change its dtype.

With np.float32:

```
>>> np.sin(np.array([0.0, np.pi / 4.0, np.pi / 2.0], dtype=np.float32))
array([ 0.        ,  0.70710683,  1.        ], dtype=float32)
```

With np.float64:

```
>>> np.sin(np.array([0.0, np.pi / 4.0, np.pi / 2.0], dtype=np.float64))
array([ 0.        ,  0.70710678,  1.        ])
```

I wish to copy the results which I get in numpy array of dtype float64 to numpy array of dtype float32 as it is, without casting/rounding off the float value.

I need something like:

```
>>> np.sin(np.array([0.0, np.pi / 4.0, np.pi / 2.0], dtype=np.float32))
array([ 0.        ,  0.70710678,  1.        ])
```

Arrays can be multi-dimensional also in some cases. Is there any way we can achieve this?

Comment: "I wish to copy the results which I get in numpy array of dtype float64 to numpy array of dtype float32 as it is, without casting/rounding off the float value."
Isn't it the essence of bit limited representation of numbers? less bits -> less accuracy?

Comment: It's hard to explain, but if you google float precision and float arithmetic in python you'll see the details.  Basically what you're trying to do isn't going to work.

Comment: This is a situation I am facing currently in my code. The rounding behavior on my arch is different than what we get on Intel. The precision values of float32 vs float64 changes by far on my arch. So basically I am looking for a way to make the values align without changing the dtype as it will break my code.